How can I use an extension method instead of defining column name?
In EF Core, when I get data from the database, I select columns to get specific data. When I use following code, everything is ok:
var result = await query.Select(x => new Models.Output.Piping.LineJoints.LineJoint2
{
    Id = x.Id,
    JointNo = x.JointNo
}).ToListAsync();

But when I use extension methods, EF Core returns all columns, then converts to model on the client side. Extension method is as follows:
public static class Ext
{
    public static Models.Output.Piping.LineJoints.LineJoint2 ToModel(
        this Domain.Entities.Piping.LineJoints.LineJoint domain)
    {
        return new Models.Output.Piping.LineJoints.LineJoint2
        {
            Id = domain.Id,
            JointNo = domain.JointNo
        };
    }
}

Using this extension method, I change the query to be like:
var result = await query.Select(x => x.ToModel()).ToListAsync();

What is best solution for this? I don't want to specify columns one by one.
As I found, the solution is defining generic method to get output type then compile type in my repository:
query = query.SelectMany(entity => selectProperties.Select(prop => prop.Compile()(entity)));

But, after this, when I use .ToListAsync(), the following exception is thrown:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Consider using a mapper that already supports EF's IQueryable such as Automapper or Mapperly. Automapper for instance has .ProjectTo<Domain.Entities.Piping.LineJoints.LineJoint>(config) where the configuration can be set up explicitly or using conventions.
